# How to parse XML values in actionscript 3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

How to parse XML element using flex 4 and actionscript 3?
If my input like this

```
<name><first>Bill</first><last>Gates</last></name>
```

And I want t get output like this

```
<name>
  <first>Bill</first>
  <last>Gates</last>
</name>
```

for a button click.And I have to set ignoreWhitespace and prettyPrinting properties are false. I don't have any idea about it. But I have to do it. Please share your ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument('<name><first>Bill</first><last>Gates</last></name>');
xml.ignoreWhite = false;

trace(xml);
// output - <name><first>Bill</first><last>Gates</last></name>

trace(XML(xml));
// output
//<name>
//  <first>Bill</first>
//  <last>Gates</last>
//</name>
```

If there is a document that does not have a structure for creating structures that can convert it into XML

Comment: but I have to set the ignoreWhiteSpace ans prettyPrinting proprties as false.

Comment: Need output as String or XML?

Comment: For both. I have to retrun as string for some functions and for some others I have to return  as an XML.

Comment: Сhanged the code for clarity. This option will suit you? If not, explain what.

Comment: I got output for your code like this "<name><first>Bill</first><last>Gates</last></name>". Please check it.